# Microstrain 3DM-GX3 and imu_drivers

Tags: ros, microstrain, imu-drivers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This question is a follow-on to the question previously answered in the thread [Any microstrain imu driver supporting 3DM-GX3 protocol?](http://answers.ros.org/question/672/any-microstrain-imu-driver-supporting-3dm-gx3).

I have a Microstrain 3DM-GX3-25 AHRS and I'm hoping to use it with ROS Diamondback on Natty.  According to the closed thread, there is a patch under imu_drivers 1.2.4.  I just added the stack using apt three days ago but I can't verify the release version.  Looking at the stack, I can see the microstrain_3dmgx2_imu package.  Is this supposed to work for the 3DM-GX3?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11649/microstrain-3dm-gx3-and-imu_drivers/) by [wkr101](https://answers.ros.org/users/858/wkr101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2011-10-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-10-23**:
You can determine the version of a stack easily by using the rosversion tool, `rosversion imu_drivers` 1.2.4 is the version released into diamondback see http://www.ros.org/wiki/imu_drivers/Releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Okay, so I have it working so I guess that answers my question.  I was able to use the microstrain_3dmgx2_imu package directly following the [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu/Tutorials/UsingTheIMUNode).

I did verify the stack version was 1.2.4 using rosversion (thanks tfoote).

---

Originally posted by [wkr101](https://answers.ros.org/users/858/wkr101/) with karma: 63 on 2011-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0